# How can I replace all but the last repeated letter in Regex?

Tags: c#, regex, backreference

Here's a table for the transform I want to do in Regex:

```
From       To
================
CAT        CAT
EGG        EGG
A          A
Z          Z
AA         ZA
BB         ZB
ZZ         ZZ
AAA        ZZA
HHHHH      ZZZZH
```

In other words, where the string is the same letter repeated 2 or more times, I want to replace all letters *except* the last one with a Z.

I'm mentally blocked here. This is what I've come up with so far, and it does not work:

```
FIND:     ^(?<=\1*?)([A-Z])(?=\1+)$
REPLACE:  Z
```

I'm unsure whether a backreference can even be used before the capture group, but either way, replacing the first `\1` with `.` doesn't help.

I'm using C#, so I'm looking for .NET-style regular expressions. I could of course do this with normal string manipulation, but I have a business-case-specific need to use regex.

Comment: Why EGG should not be replaced with EZG?

Comment: Because strings that are not comprised *entirely* of the same character repeated should be left unchanged.

Comment: Btw I don't think regexes can be applied to this case because your language is not regular, not context free in this case, because the regex has to know somehow which character should be repeating, and this is not context free (I think...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did somebody order some [dark magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591222/how-can-i-replace-all-but-the-last-repeated-letter-in-regex#comment13719278_10591901)?

```
FIND:    \G([A-Z])(?=\1)
REPLACE: Z
```

`\G` anchors each match EITHER to the beginning of the string like `\A` does, OR to the position where the previous match ended.  In other words, the `([A-Z])` in your regex always tries to match the very next character, and thanks to the lookahead - `(?=\1)` - you know the next character is the same as the one you just replaced.

Also, the regex in your self-answer doesn't work for me.  The `+` isn't doing anything useful (you only care about the next character, after all), but it doesn't hurt anything either.  What got it to work for me was removing the `$`.

UPDATE: I didn't catch the requirement that the string has to be two or more of the same character *and nothing else*.  That means the `+` and the `$` are both required.  While I'm at, I'll address the added requirement that the strings `XX`, `XXX`, `II` and `III` should be left alone.  Voilà!

```
\G(?!\A(?:XXX?|III?)$)([A-Z])(?=\1+$)
```

Comment: Awesome! I had to make one minor change: `\G([A-Z])(?=\1+$)`. Without the `+$` in the lookahead, it would convert `HHHHG` into `ZZZHG` instead of leaving it alone (like "EGG"). That's where I was going with that `+` and `$` in my original answer. Apparently I need to brush up on anchors, I don't use them very often other than `^` and `$`.

One caveat I didn't mention -- XX, II, XXX, and III have to be excluded from this replacement in my actual app. So in the end, I'll probably have to stick to my non-RegEx replacement code.

Comment: +1 Nice, using the \G anchor, forcing a match where last one left off. This is way faster than a look behind. Adding the (?=\1+$) really completes the circut.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, just match your desired character first and then do the lookahead and lookbehind, including the anchors in those and not in the main expression, since you want the expression to match character by character.

```
([A-Z])(?<=^\1*)(?=\1+$)
```

It will not be very performant, though, because it's walking the whole string for each character.

You'd be better off using a regex to detect that the string is composed of the same character, and then replacing all characters except the last with Z's with the normal string replace method, or creating a string of Zs the length of the original one minus one, and appending the first char of the original one, for example.

Comment: +1 This is probably the magic regex that does it via replace. I keep forgetting how much of a difference variable length look behind makes.

Comment: It doesen't make a matching difference in this case, but glancing at the optional `\1*` seems misleading. `([A-Z])(?<=^\1+)(?=\1+$)` might make a performance difference, not sure.

Comment: I went with Alan's for slightly simpler expression, but +1 for a working answer and rightfully mentioning the performance aspect.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like a match then replace might work.

```
string [] Samps = {  "CAT",  "EGG",  "A",  "Z",  "AA",  "BB",  "ZZ",  "AAA",  "HHHHH" };
foreach (var item in Samps)
{
    string line = item + "\t\t";
    line += Regex.Match(item, @"^([A-Z])\1+$").Success ?
            Regex.Replace(item, @".(?!$)", "Z") :
            item;
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Output

```
CAT             CAT
EGG             EGG
A               A
Z               Z
AA              ZA
BB              ZB
ZZ              ZZ
AAA             ZZA
HHHHH           ZZZZH
```